# TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently having trouble executing nesting with Django rest framework, I think the problem is in my loop but cant't get that I have gone through most of the answers but no help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

### MODEL

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)


    class sub_category(models.Model): 
        parentCategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, 
        related_name='subcategories',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)

    class childern(models.Model):
        parentCategory = models.ForeignKey(sub_category, blank=True, null=True, 
        related_name='subcategories',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)
```

### Searlizers

```
    class ChildernSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
   
        class Meta:
            model = childern
            fields = ['name',
              'id',]

     class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
         subcategories = ChildernSerializer(many=True)
         class Meta:
             model = sub_category
             fields = ['name',
              'subcategories',
              'id',]

         def create(self, validated_data):
             sub_cat = validated_data.pop('subcategories')
             name = Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
             for cat in sub_cat:
                 sub_category.objects.create(**cat, name=name)
             return name

    class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        subcategories = SubCategorySerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = [
            'name',
            'subcategories',

               ]

        def create(self, validated_data):
            sub_cat = validated_data.pop('subcategories')
            name = Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
            for cat in sub_cat:
                sub_category.objects.create(**cat, name=name)
            return name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pop the `name` from the `cat` data, otherwise the name will both occur in the `cat` *and* through the `name=name` parameter:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    sub_cat = validated_data.pop('subcategories')
    name = Category.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for cat in sub_cat:
        cat.pop('name', None)
        sub_category.objects.create(**cat, name=name)
    return name
```

Comment: It did not allow the direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set

Comment: @Osama; that ls likely because your `cat`s contain `children`, which is similar like the problem you encounter with the `subcategories`, you will thus need to add a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because the property `Name` was passed twice in your call to create:

```
sub_category.objects.create(**cat, name=name)
```

`name` already exists within `**cat` and you also passed it with   `name=name`

simply remove `name` it from `SubCategorySerializer` so it become:

```
class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
     subcategories = ChildernSerializer(many=True)
     class Meta:
         model = sub_category
         fields = ['subcategories',
          'id',]
```